# Excel, how to always force a font format regardless of what is input?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically, my question is, is there any way to set a font for my table or certain cells, and whatever I paste into them, they'd be a font I selected beforehand ?

I'm doing a monthly review of data, and I copy and paste a lot of it, but they're always different fonts and I have to change it back and it gets annoying, as I have to change the font about 100 times every month.

I tried setting the default font for my table, but when I input a different font, it doesn't automatically change it to the one I want.

Thank you in advance,

Patrick.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL-A on an empty sheet will select all the cells (also same: click above `1`/left of `A`).
Set the font you wish to have and save the spreadsheet.

Now as you're about to paste, make sure to paste only text;
i.e. Paste special, then select Text or Unicode text
*(LibreOffice has Text and 'Unformatted Text' as options present at the same time as Paste special; in the 'Right click' menu)*.

For single cell content; EDIT the cell (hit F2!), then paste.

Note: There is a setting that specifies the default paste, set it to "Text only" (from memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively paste the cells you want to keep the original font.

[image]